# Differentiating a distribution function does not give me a density

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

Let $X_i$, $i=1,2,3$ be three independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda_i$. Define $R_1=\min\{X_1,X_3\}$ and $R_2=\min\{X_2,X_3\}$.

Then, $R_1$ and $R_2$ are obviously not independent. The distribution function is:
$$P(R_1<r_1,R_2<r_2)=1-P(R_1>r_1)-P(R_2>r_2)+P(R_1>r_1,R_2>r_2),$$
where $P(R_i>r_i)=e^{-(\lambda_i+\lambda_3)r_i}$, $i=1,2$ and $P(R_1>r_1,R_2>r_2)=e^{-\lambda_1 r_1}e^{-\lambda_2 r_2}e^{-\lambda_3 \max\{r_1,r_2\}}$.

Now, this means that the distribution function $F_{(R_1,R_2)}(r_1,r_2)$ is given by
$$F_{(R_1,R_2)}(r_1,r_2)=\begin{cases} 1 -e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_3)r_1}-e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)r_2}+ e^{-\lambda_1 r_1}e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_3) r_2}, \mbox{ if } r_1<r_2 \\  1-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_3)r_1}-e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)r_2}+e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_3) r_1}e^{-\lambda_2 r_2}, \mbox{ if } r_1>r_2 \end{cases}.$$

However, when I differentiate this function to obtain the density, i.e $f_{(R_1,R_2)}(r_1,r_2)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r_1 \partial r_2}F_{(R_1,R_2)}(r_1,r_2)$ I do not get a function that integrates to $1$ on $(0,\infty)^2$. I get,
$$f_{(R_1,R_2)}(r_1,r_2)=\begin{cases} \lambda_1 (\lambda_2+\lambda_3)e^{-\lambda_1 r_1}e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_3) r_2}, \mbox{ if } r_1<r_2 \\ \lambda_2(\lambda_1+\lambda_3)e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_3) r_1}e^{-\lambda_2 r_2}, \mbox{ if } r_1>r_2 \end{cases}.$$

Observe that $F$ is indeed a distribution function (continuous, increasing, $F(0,r_2)=F(r_1,0)=0$ and $F(r_1,r_2)\to 1$ as $(r_1,r_2)\to (\infty,\infty)$. So I expect that the derivative should give me a proper density function, but I get
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f_{(R_1,R_2)}(r_1,r_2) dr_1 dr_1= 1-\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}.$$

Where is the mistake? I must admit I'm a bit puzzled about this... there must be a very silly mistake somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because the cdf $F$ is discontinuous across the line $r_1 = r_2$. Think of a 1d case where $F(x) = \mathbf{1}\{x \geq 0\}$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$; if you differentiate  ignoring $x = 0$ you get a "density" $f(x) = 0$ which is clearly not adequate

Comment: The cdf F I got is continous at the diagonal, that is why I got so confused :) but probably the cdf I got is not correct due to the observation in the answer.

Comment: There may be a typo in your cdf then. On a second pass, it seems the probabilities $P[R_i > r_i]$ were inputted incorrectly.

Comment: The probabilities $P[R_i>r_i]$ seem correct to me: minimum of two exponentials is exponential again. What did you mean?

Comment: No I meant in your expression for $F_{R_1, R_2}$ you inputted $e^{-\lambda_i r_i}$ instead of $e^{-(\lambda_i + \lambda_3) r_i}$ each time

Comment: Aha! There yes, it was a typo! I had it correctly in my notes. I will fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there *is* a density function?

Some of the time $X_3$ will be the smallest of the three $X_i$, and when that happens $R_1=R_2$.  That is, $P[R_1=R_2]>0$, and some of the probability mass of the joint distribution of $(R_1,R_2)$ is concentrated on the set $\{(r,r):r>0\}$, a set of Lebesgue measure zero in the plane.

If you have the visualization tools handy, you can generate a thousand or so Monte Carlo sample values of $(R_1,R_2)$ and plot a 2-D histogram to see what the empirical density looks like.